# How do I use count from one resource to another resource in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, azure-aks

**Aim**: Create a TF module for AKs cluster with default node pool and additional node pool. Then consume this Terraform module

```
data "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "private_dns_zone" {
  provider            = azurerm.management
  name                = var.private_dns_zone
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name_mg
}
resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "azuser_assigned_identity" {
  count                   = var.no_of_clusters
  name                    = "${var.tla}-aks-${local.lookup_result}-identity-${count.index+1}"
  location                = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name     = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

    lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      tags
    ]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "azure_role_assign" {
  #count                = var.rbac_assignment == true ? 1 : 0
  count                 = var.no_of_clusters
  scope                = data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.private_dns_zone.id
  role_definition_name = "Private DNS Zone Contributor"
  principal_id         = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.azuser_assigned_identity[count.index].principal_id
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
  count                   = var.no_of_clusters
  name                    = "${var.tla}-aks-${local.lookup_result}-${count.index+1}"
  location                = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name     = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  dns_prefix              = var.dns_prefix
  private_dns_zone_id     = data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.private_dns_zone.id
  kubernetes_version      = var.kubernetes_version
  sku_tier                = var.sku_tier
  private_cluster_enabled = var.enable_private_cluster
  #api_server_authorized_ip_ranges = ""
  default_node_pool {
    name                  = "syspool001"
    orchestrator_version  = var.orchestrator_version
    availability_zones    = var.agents_availability_zones
    enable_auto_scaling   = true
    node_count            = var.default_pool_node_count
    max_count             = var.default_pool_max_node_count
    min_count             = var.default_pool_min_node_count
    max_pods              = var.default_pool_max_pod_count
    vm_size               = var.agents_size
    enable_node_public_ip = false
    os_disk_size_gb       = var.default_pool_os_disk_size_gb
    type                  = "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
    vnet_subnet_id        = var.vnet_subnet_id
    node_labels           = var.agents_labels
    tags                  = merge(local.tags, var.agents_tags)
  }

  network_profile {
    network_plugin     = var.network_plugin
    network_policy     = var.network_policy
    dns_service_ip     = var.net_profile_dns_service_ip
    docker_bridge_cidr = var.net_profile_docker_bridge_cidr
    service_cidr       = var.net_profile_service_cidr
  }

  role_based_access_control {
    enabled = true
    azure_active_directory {
      managed                = true
      admin_group_object_ids = var.rbac_aad_admin_group_object_ids
    }
  }

  identity {
    type = "UserAssigned"
    user_assigned_identity_id = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.azuser_assigned_identity[count.index].id
    }

  addon_profile {
    azure_policy {
      enabled = true
    }

    http_application_routing {
      enabled = false
    }

    oms_agent {
      enabled                    = true
      log_analytics_workspace_id = data.azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.log_analytics.id
    }
  }

  tags = local.tags

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      default_node_pool,tags
    ]
  }
depends_on  = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.azuser_assigned_identity, azurerm_role_assignment.azure_role_assign]
}

 resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool" "aksnp" {
    lifecycle {
     ignore_changes = [
       node_count
     ]
   }
   #count                 = var.no_of_clusters
   for_each              = var.additional_node_pools
   kubernetes_cluster_id = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks[index(keys(var.additional_node_pools), each.value)].id
   name                  = each.value.node_os == "Windows" ? substr(each.key, 0, 6) : substr(each.key, 0, 12)
   node_count            = each.value.node_count
   vm_size               = each.value.vm_size
   availability_zones    = each.value.zones
   max_pods              = each.value.max_pods
   os_disk_size_gb       = each.value.os_disk_size_gb
   os_type               = each.value.node_os
   vnet_subnet_id        = var.vnet_subnet_id
   node_taints           = each.value.taints
   enable_auto_scaling   = each.value.cluster_auto_scaling
   min_count             = each.value.cluster_auto_scaling_min_count
   max_count             = each.value.cluster_auto_scaling_max_count
 }
```

I am declaring additional node pools as like below:

```
variable "additional_node_pools" {
  description = "Additional/Optional VM's required to run pods"
  type = map(object({
    node_count                     = number
    max_pods                       = number
    os_disk_size_gb                = number
    vm_size                        = string
    zones                          = list(string)
    node_os                        = string
    taints                         = list(string)
    cluster_auto_scaling           = bool
    cluster_auto_scaling_min_count = number
    cluster_auto_scaling_max_count = number
  }))
}
```

My question is **how do I reference the count.index from the AKS cluster in the additional node pool**?

I want to utilize this module like below:

```
module "aks_cluster_a" {
  source                            = "app.terraform.io/xxxx/aks/azurerm"
  version                           = "0.9.31"
  no_of_clusters                    = 2
  azurerm_cluster_subscription_id   = var.azurerm_cluster_subscription_id
  azurerm_mgmt_subscription_id      = var.azurerm_mgmt_subscription_id
  azurerm_tenant_id                 = var.azurerm_tenant_id
  azurerm_client_id                 = var.azurerm_client_id
  azurerm_secret_id                 = var.azurerm_secret_id
  kubernetes_version                = "1.20.7"
  orchestrator_version              = "1.20.7"
  rbac_assignment                   = true
  log_analytics_workspace_name      = "xxxxxxxxxd-log-analytics-workspace"
  log_analytics_resource_group_name = "xxxxxxx-non-prod-loganalytics"
  resource_group_name               = "xxxx-dev-aae"
  tla                               = "xxx"
  dns_prefix                        = "xxx"
  resource_group_name_mg            = "coredns-nonproduction"
  vnet_subnet_id                    = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/odessa-non-prod-shared-aae/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/NonProdAEVnet/subnets/aks-controlled-01"
  default_pool_min_node_count = 3
  default_pool_node_count     = 3
  default_pool_max_node_count = 6
  default_pool_max_pod_count  = 12
  private_dns_zone            = "privatelink.australiaeast.azmk8s.io"
  additional_node_pools = {
    pool1 = {
      node_count                     = "1"
      max_pods                       = "40"
      os_disk_size_gb                = "64"
      vm_size                        = "Standard_D4s_v3"
      zones                          = ["1", "2", "3"]
      node_os                        = "Linux"
      taints                         = ["kubernetes.io/os=windows:NoSchedule"]
      cluster_auto_scaling           = true
      cluster_auto_scaling_min_count = "2"
      cluster_auto_scaling_max_count = "4"
    }
  }

  agents_tags = {
    Application  = "AKS - Standalone Cluster XXX"
    CostCentre   = "0000"
    Environment  = "DEV"
    ManagedBy    = "SD-Cloud"
    Owner        = "xxxxxxxx"
    Support      = "xxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

I get errors like the below:

```
Error: Error in function call
│
│   on .terraform/modules/aks_cluster_a/main.tf line 111, in resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool" "aksnp":
│  111:    kubernetes_cluster_id = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks[index(keys(var.additional_node_pools), each.value)].id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is object with 10 attributes
│     │ var.additional_node_pools is map of object with 1 element
│
│ Call to function "index" failed: item not found.
╵
╷
│ Error: Error in function call
│
│   on .terraform/modules/aks_cluster_b/main.tf line 111, in resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool" "aksnp":
│  111:    kubernetes_cluster_id = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks[index(keys(var.additional_node_pools), each.value)].id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is object with 10 attributes
│     │ var.additional_node_pools is map of object with 1 element
│
│ Call to function "index" failed: item not found.
```

Comment: What have you tried? You should be able to reference `count.index` within the `additional_node_pools` block.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by "consume this module"?

Comment: Mark B added an error message. Marcin, consume meaning once I create module out of it, I want us that module.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks[index(keys(var.additional_node_pools), each.key)].id` seeing as you're iterating over a map?